# How to get work easyui js on divs which are written by another js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-easyui

I have an javascript class that produces html code. I can produce html code properly, without any error. In this time I am producing some divs which are supposed to be accoridon layout for easyui implemetation. However when I produce my accordion divs, easyui doesn't see them and does not anything on them.

I tried to include my producer class both  before and after easyui scripts. But it does not work.

If I have to be more clear I will write some code but consider this as pseudocode not real code, this code is only for me to express myself better:

For example this is my acordion div:

```
<div class="easyui-accordion" id="accordion2"  href="#"><div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
var myContent="<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true"    
id="mydivid">OrtoFoto TVK</a>";

document.getElementById("acordion2").innerHTML=myContent;
```

In this example the button elementinside div#accordion2 is displayed on browser as I set in js, but easyui does not effect it.

When I don't include my producer class and  write  my html like this easyui works on the div:

```
<div class="easyui-accordion" id="accordion2"  href="#">
  <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true" id="mydivid">
    OrtoFoto TVK
  </a>
<div>
```

How can solve this? Thanks...

Comment: There is a ">" at the start of your myContent string that I think should be deleted.

Comment: I am sory for code, it is not the real code, I have written it for just expressing myself. Please consider it as pseudocode. Actually I am sure that my problem is not about syntax and my code is too long. So I did not write the real code. I just want to get some ideas about this issue.

Comment: Ok. No worries I will post a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. When you are working with strings you have to be careful if you start with a double quotation and you need another set of double quotation in the string you have to escape them. If you look at the string that you have you see how it is not one solid color its red and gray but mine is all red. That is a hint that your string is not a string.

However all i did was change the first and last to single quotes.

```
 var myContent='<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true"  id="mydivid">OrtoFoto TVK</a>';
```

I have never used easy-ui but what i noticed was that if you do not put a 'title' attribute within a div that is nested inside your accordion it does not show the nested elements.

So after changing the string i added a div with a title

```
 var myContent='<div title="test"><a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true" id="mydivid">OrtoFoto TVK</a></div>';
```

And that seems to work how you wanted to i think. Here is a working example in jsBin.

http://jsbin.com/#/ocIFosox/1/edit